# Is there an offensive word or phrase a learner might accidentally say by mispronouncing "젓가락"?

Tags: pronunciation

When I was last in Korea a few years ago a local friend of mine told me that I was actually saying something like "F*ck off" whenever I tried to say "chopsticks", "젓가락".

Was my friend just having a joke at my expense or is there actually an offensive term or phrase that sounds similar to "젓가락" when spoken by somebody with a foreign accent?

Comment: I think it's 좆까라.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

좆까라 literally means "show me your penis", and figuratively means "fuck off". For obvious reasons, it only makes sense when heavily stressed and aggressively used towards a man.

Given context and its relative rarity, no one would actually mistake a bad accent for swearing.

Comment: Thanks! Verified by this decade old thread I found with the help of this answer: http://forums.eslcafe.com/korea/viewtopic.php?t=27158&start=15